# Ingesting Azure DevOps Data

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm considering using Azure Functions to ingest event data from multiple ADO projects.

I would like to configure Web Hooks for each event in ADO, to post via HTTP.

I appreciate that each function must have exactly one trigger, and so can a single HTTP trigger handle multiple different web hooks? If so, would Azure functions scale out to create multiple instances of functions, should multiple events occur at the same time?

Comment: There is no code associated with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a service bus as a target of your service connection. Then you may configure your function app trigger to the service bus queue. In this case, the function app will resolve all scalability issues by default.

[image]